# Как связаны части предложения, разделеные запятой и союзом либо?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, смысл, анализ-текста

Относится ли "по делу об административном правонарушении, предусмотренном той же статьей" к "постановления о назначении административного наказания"?

**...наличие по одному и тому же факту совершения противоправных действий (бездействия) лицом, в отношении которого ведется производство по делу об административном правонарушении, постановления о назначении административного наказания, либо постановления о прекращении производства по делу об административном правонарушении, предусмотренном той же статьей или той же частью статьи настоящего Кодекса или закона субъекта Российской Федерации, либо постановления о возбуждении уголовного дела**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы было понятнее, перепишем отрывок так:

...наличие по одному и тому же факту совершения противоправных действий (бездействия) лицом, в отношении которого ведется производство по делу об административном правонарушении, одного из следующих постановлений:

- **постановления о назначении административного наказания**,
- постановления о прекращении производства **по делу об административном правонарушении, предусмотренном той же статьей** или той же частью статьи настоящего Кодекса или закона субъекта Российской Федерации,
- постановления о возбуждении уголовного дела

Указанные в вопросе слова выделены жирным шрифтом.
Теперь легко понять, что ответ на Ваш вопрос (относится ли "по делу об административном правонарушении, предусмотренном той же статьей" к "постановления о назначении административного наказания") — **отрицательный**.

Comment: спасибо огромное, я так же считаю, надеюсь судьи согласятся!

Answer (score 1):

**Разделительный союз ЛИБО выражает взаимоисключение** перечисляемых ситуаций. Запятая ставится в случае повторения союза и не ставится, если он одиночный, но значение союза от этого не меняется.

В данном случае требуется наличие **одного постановления из трех возможных вариантов:**  (1) о назначении административного наказания, (2) о прекращении производства по делу об административном правонарушении, (3)  о возбуждении уголовного дела.

Дополнительно указано, что постановления (1) и (2) регулируются одной и той же статёй Кодекса.